# What are some other alternatives to phpGrid?

Tags: php, jqgrid, crud

We are looking at some grid based CRUD tools and ran into phpGrid. We like what we see so far and were wondering if someone else had any experiences with some other tools that we may evaluate.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpGrid looks like it is just a PHP wrapper for jqGrid. You might consider looking at [jqGrid for PHP](http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx), or if you want a free solution you can just use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) directly as a jQuery plugin.